# Polytopes and polyhedral cones in complex Euclidean space

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Given $A \in \mathsf{M}_{m \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the *polyhedron with respect to $A$ and $b$*, denoted by $P(A,b)$, is defined by 
$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \le b \}.$$
If $P(A,b)$ is compact, then $P(A,b)$ is called a *polytope*; if $b=0$, then $P(A,b)$ is called a *polyhedral cone*.

As is well-known, $P(A,b)$ is a polytope if and only if there are vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(A,b) = \text{conv}(\{v_1,\dots,v_k\})$. Similary, $P(A,0)$ is polyhedral cone if and only if there are vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(A,0) = \text{coni}(\{v_1,\dots,v_k\})$.

In $\mathbb{C}^n$, it seems reasonable to define a polytope and polyhderal cone as the convex hull and conical hull of a finite collection of vectors, respectively.

The map $f: \mathbb{C}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ defined by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ \vdots \\ z_n \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^n 
\longmapsto
\begin{bmatrix} \Re z_1 \\ \Im z_1 \\ \vdots \\ \Re z_n \\ \Im z_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2n} 
$$
is a linear isomorphism (here $\mathbb{C}^n$ is viewed as a real, $2n$-dimensional vector space). With the definition above, $V$ is a polytope (respectively, polyhedral cone) in $\mathbb{C}^n$ if and only if $f(V)$ is a polytope (respectively, polyhedral cone) in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

**Questions:**

1. Have polytopes/convex polyhedra been defined this way in complex Euclidean space?
2. Has this observation been made before?
3. If so, is there a suitable reference?

Answer (score 2):

One text to consult is [Complex Convexity and Analytic Functionals](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-7871-5) by Andersson, Passare, and Sigurdsson. They give and discuss a number of definitions, including the basic one (a set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is *convex* if its intersection with any complex line is contractible), which looks like a generalisation of your definition.